# Why is this code not affecting the output?

Tags: c++

This is supposed to take the input and move each letter 1 to the right. Is the pause stopping it from doing anything?

How can I change it so that it doesn't just output what the user inputs?

This is the code in C++ in Visual Studio Community 2013:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <cctype>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string cyphertext;
    cout << "Paste your cyphertext and press enter to shift right 1: ";
    cin >> cyphertext;

    void encrypt(char * cyphertext, unsigned int offset);

    for (int i = 0; cyphertext[i] != 0; i++) {
        char firstLetter = islower(cyphertext[i]) ? 'a' : 'A';
        unsigned int alphaOffset = cyphertext[i] - firstLetter;
        int offset = 0;
        unsigned int newAlphaOffset = alphaOffset + offset;
        cyphertext[i] = firstLetter + newAlphaOffset % 26;

        cout << "" << "Right One: " << cyphertext;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to actually compile...

Comment: It is very easy to determine what effect the pausing has — remove that line and run the program again. But why are you declaring a function called "encrypt" which you never define or use?

Comment: While I doubt it has anything to do with your problem, you set `offset` to 0, then immediately use it in `newAlphaOffset = alphaOffset + offset`, is this intentional?

Comment: Zenzelezz, there was an error that offset was undefined. That's why I did that.

Answer (score 2):

Your `pause` is inside the 'encrypting' loop.  It needs to be outside.  The `return` in the loop will terminate the program; that too needs to be outside the loop.

Note that it is easier to see such mistakes when the code is indented in an orthodox layout such as the one now in the question.  Working with scratty layouts makes it really hard to see many problems that are obvious when the code is tidily laid out.

You also declare a function `encrypt()` which you never use; don't do that.  And it's generally a bad idea to declare functions inside other functions.  And given that there isn't an `encrypt()` function defined, there isn't a 'void function', so I've changed the question title for you.